# Why doesn't a quantum wave propagate with a speed of $p/m$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction

A light wave propagates at a speed c because it's energy equation is:

$$E=pc$$

so it's wave equation is:

$$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}$$

which is a wave propagating with the speed of light.

For massive objects, the energy relation is: $E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$

For quantum wave, schrodinger's equation:

$$-\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} = i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}$$

which produces a wave with propagation speed $\frac{k}{2m}$ which comes from:

$$w = \frac{k^2}{2m} = \frac{k}{2m} k$$

All of this makes sense, but shouldn't the wave be propagating at speed $p/m$? I don't understand how $$\frac{d\langle x \rangle}{dt} = \frac{\langle p \rangle}{m}$$ is not contradictory with the above result. The wave is propagating with half the speed.

Comment: I stumbled upon a similar "contradiction" many years ago, when these things were fresh in my mind. The resolution came from appreciating the difference between group velocity and phase velocity.

Comment: but isn't the wave as a whole moving at the same speed?

Comment: What is "the wave as a whole"? What exactly do each of your speeds (implicit in the problem) represent? See this animation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity#%3A%7E%3Atext%3DThe_phase_velocity_is%3A_v%2Ctravel_undistorted_at_this_velocity.?wprov=sfla1